# PYTHONPATH not working for sudo on GNU/Linux (works for root)

Tags: python, linux, macos, bash, pythonpath

EDIT: Works for root, sudo is the problem. Read below.

I have a directory with my own libraries, e.g. my Python libraries are located at `/home/name/lib/py`.
I've added this directory to **Python's PATH** for all users (including root) by adding the following line to `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/name/lib/py
```

It works for all users (including root). But it doesn't work for sudo. Is there any way I can make sudo use `/etc/bash.bashrc`?

EDIT: More information:

I've added `PYTHONPATH` to sudoers file like so: `Defaults env_keep += "HOME PYTHONPATH"`. It sitll doesn't work.

```
env | grep PYTHON:
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
    PYTHONPATH=/home/name/lib/py

sudo env | grep PYTHON:
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

sudo echo $PYTHONPATH:
    /home/name/lib/py
```

Comment: You might try over at [su] as well, thought I don't think this needs migrating.

Comment: Especially with your edit that the problem is with `sudo` and not anything Python specific, this would probably get more useful answers on SU as mentioned, or on unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @brc I realize that now. I've fixed it though -- see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The fix in my case was to remove `Defaults !env_reset` from sudoers.

But, I had to keep `Defaults env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` in sudoers.
I've actually added `Defaults env_reset` (which resets environment variables), but it still works because of `env_keep`.

It seems that `env_keep` and `!env_reset` conflict with eachother, but that's just a guess.

---

So, the whole process:

1. add `export PYTHONPATH=/your/custom/path` to `~/.bashrc` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`
2. add `PYTHONPATH` to `Defaults env_keep += "ENV1 ENV2 ..."` in sudoers file
3. remove `Defaults !env_reset` from sudoers file if present

Comment: This solution also works on OS X. Just add a line `Defaults        env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` in /etc/sudoers on OS X.

Answer (score 25):

The same is true for the `PATH` variable, it's also not carried into the super user environment, even though you're passing the preserve environment flag `-E`.

I'm using this sudo command now without any other modifications:

```
sudo -HE env PATH=$PATH PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH ./bin/myscript
```

Since it's an alternative approach that works (for me) I thought I'd share here.

Comment: The `-H` option is related to the home of target user. I didn't need it for your example to work here. Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives to manipulating `PYTHONPATH`:

- [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)
- [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another tip:

```
sudo echo $PYTHONPATH:
    /home/name/lib/py
```

It won't work. Shell will interpret it like this:

1) expand $PYTHONPATH from env variable for example: /usr/lib/python

2) execute "sudo echo /usr/lib/python"

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be posted somewhere else. But sudo will not process the environment file by default. If you want to invoke that the -i flag should help you out. It will simulate that users initial login.

You may have to play around with where you're putting your variables too. http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Comment: sudo -i also didn't work for me. I think something somehow conflicted with `!env_reset` option in sudoers file (which I think is actually identical to sudo -i). See my answer for full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow configuration helps me to run multiple python services in dedicated VENVs
on one Centos host

1. Export env variables to separate file, for example `/etc/sysconfig/my-app`
2. Set `EnvironmentFile` option in service config

see code below:

```
-bash-4.2$ sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/my-app

PATH=/usr/local/my-app/env/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/my-app/env/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH



-bash-4.2$ sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/my-app.service

[Unit]
Description=my-app daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/my_app
User=app_user
Group=app_user
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/my-app/env/bin/python /usr/local/my-app/main.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```