# Can't import jinja2

Tags: python, pip, jinja2

I installed jinja2 via pip, but in python 2.7.8 which is compiled by myself, the module cannot be imported. (The default version shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 is 2.7.6, and that one can import jinja2)

```
[drizzlex@dx ~]
$ ls /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
easy-install.pth          markupsafe/               netaddr-0.7.12.egg-info/
jinja2/                   MarkupSafe-0.23.egg-info/ 
Jinja2-2.7.3.egg-info/    netaddr/     



[drizzlex@dx ~]
$ ls -l `which python`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Nov  3 20:13 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python2

[drizzlex@dx ~]
$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov  2 2014, 01:04:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import jinja2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named jinja2
>>>
```

Please give me some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dist-packages` is a Debian-specific enhancement to Python which is only present on the version of Python installed with the distro - and which contains libraries installed by the system package manager. The version you've complied yourself doesn't know anything about it. You'll need to install a separate version of Jinja2 using `pip` (and preferably use a virtualenv).

Comment: Pip will install jinja2 to  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages, though my default python is 2.7.8 now.

Comment: You need to install pip for your new version of Python. (There isn't a separate package dir per point version though, your packages will be installed in python2.7/site-packages).

Comment: I think I will remove python 2.7.8 and use virtualenv this time.

Comment: I install jinja2 using pip but then can't import it, it doesn't really install it (sudo pip install jinja2). So I had to specify target and it worked ( sudo pip install --target /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ jinja2 ).  It used to work but now can't install anything with pip. Even though it think it install it, it does not. This fixes it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712468/install-error-thinks-pythonpath-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

You should probably review the `sys.path` used by your self-compiled Python 2.7.8.