# Can't import module when using root user

Tags: python

What should I do if I can import a module when I run python, but not when I run sudo python?

For example:

```
whoami
    rose
python
>>> import mymodule
>>>
```

.

```
sudo python
>>> import mymodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mymodule
```

I had run `sudo chown -R rose:rose` on the package containing this module.

`sudo which python` and `which python` both print `/usr/bin/python`.

I'm running Linux.

Comment: Most likely `$PYTHONPATH` is different, or not even set, for your root user.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did have to put the module on my `$PYTHONPATH`, but `echo $PYTHONPATH` and `sudo echo $PYTHONPATH` print the same thing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that would be odd. When you run a command with `sudo` the environment variables are the same.  That is for linux, and only if the command is run from the same shell process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969540/pythonpath-not-working-for-sudo-on-gnu-linux-works-for-root could be what is going on

Comment: Have you tried comparing the results of print(sys.path) in each case?

Comment: @karthikr I added `Defaults env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` to `/etc/sudoers` and now it works.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Linux.

Answer (score 14):

The `sudo` environment did not contain my `PYTHONPATH`, becuase my `/etc/sudoers` contains `Defaults env_reset`. I simply added `Defaults env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` to `/etc/sudoers` and now it works.

Comment: Actually, did you also try sudo -E -H options? This will preserve your environment variables... if this is not a risk for you to use it's the easier way.

Comment: Mayou36 is correct however the -H option sets the HOME environment variable to what is in the password database entry.  In my case sudo -E by itself was sufficient to retain the PYTHONPATH and allow the library, in my case, 'uinput' to be used.

Comment: @Mayou36 Please post that as an answer

Comment: Neither option worked for me