# cannot import mongoengine from a python file which require SUDO to execute

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I want to import `mongoengine` in a python file which requires `sudo` to execute but I am getting the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mongoengine'`. I have tried the following:
1/ In terminal I have opened python shell and written `pip show mongoengine` and it can detect the version and location which means that library is installed correctly.
2/ I have tried to run the code by removing the `sudo required part` then also code has executed.
Which strength the point that using `sudo python3 pyfile_name.py` is causing the problem.
I am using it in a Flaks environment. Below I am giving the example code.

**mongo_data.py**

```
from mongoengine import *
from random import random, randint

connect(
    db='db_name',
    host='localhost',
    port=27017
)

class Mongo_User(Document):
    user_id = SequenceField(primary_key=True)
    json_data = DictField()
    meta = {'collection': "col_name"}
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response
from flask import jsonify
from mongo_data import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = os.path.abspath("templates/static/")

@app.route('/get_json_for_form')
def parse_get_json_for_form(name=None):
    user = Mongo_User()
    json_data = {"name":"xyz"} # sample data
    user.json_data = json_data
    user.save()
    return jsonify(json_data)
```

In my case, `app.py` must be run with `sudo python3 app.py` and which is causing the problem I guess. Any idea to overcome the problem is highly appreciable.

Comment: I'd ask myself: why does the script require to be run as superuser? Especially so if it's a web server.

Comment: it is at R&D purpose stage right now running on Xilinx FPGA

Comment: Are you really running a Flask web server on Python on a Xilinx FPGA?

Comment: Sorry, mixed the device. Flask running on ARM processor,  xilinx FPGA word is used as it is using to process data. Wrongly used the term.

Comment: You still don't need to run Python as root. Just make sure whatever device file represents the Xilinx is readable by a regularly user...

Comment: obviously, I should run my python script as `root` as I know what else I am doing there/ use there.

Comment: Obviously your possibly internet-facing server script won't ever have a vulnerability that would allow e.g. reading an arbitrary file or executing arbitrary code? :)

Comment: it is an R&D purpose issue so the cause of `vulnerability` is not counted here. I know what you mean. I am using here a library dedicated for xilinx FPGA which require `root` permission and I need some data from that lib so I run the flask with `root` permission. During deployment that specific lib will not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer by following [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346171/cant-import-module-when-using-root-user#comment67171986_25346281). Just used

```
sudo -E python3 app.py
```

Another way has also found but don't think as a recommended one

```
sudo python3 -m pip install mongoengine
```