# ImportError with Conda

Tags: python, numpy, conda

I have installed conda and now I want to use modul *numpy* in my python script, but I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

I can see the module under `conda list`, I have my `$PATH` set to `/path/to/anaconda2/bin`, `conda info -a` says I have not set `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH` as some answers suggest...

How to set conda / enviroment variables right co I can use *numpy*?

Comment: What is the output of `which python`? What about `python -c "import sys; sys.path"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in env variables and running the script as sudo as described here [PYTHONPATH not working for sudo on GNU/Linux (works for root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969540/pythonpath-not-working-for-sudo-on-gnu-linux-works-for-root)

Comment: Did you have to specify PYTHONPATH eventually?. I'm having the same problem, but adding `Defaults        env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` to sudoers doesn't fix it.

Comment: Moreover `sudo python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` outputs the wrong path whereas the non sudo one prints the activated conda env