# No module named future

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian

I am running a telegram bot in python and i am using python3.6 on raspbian ( pi3 )

Below is my imports:

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, division,
                    print_function, unicode_literals)
from builtins import (
    bytes, dict, int, list, object, range, str,
    ascii, chr, hex, input, next, oct, open,
    pow, round, super,
    filter, map, zip)
from uuid import uuid4

import re
import telegram

from telegram.utils.helpers import escape_markdown

from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, ParseMode, \
    InputTextMessageContent
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler
import logging
import random
import telepot
import unicodedata
import json
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

When i try to run my bot with sudo python3 bot.py i get

```
ImportError: No module named 'future'
```

I have searched and found many answers on this but none have worked for me such as `pip install future` and `pip3 install future` The module does show in my lib for python 3.6 [future in lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvTXE.png)

Any idea why it still says `No module named future`? ?

Comment: is there a reason you are running with `sudo`? That will clobber your environment which is why python can't find installed modules

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PYTHONPATH not working for sudo on GNU/Linux (works for root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969540/pythonpath-not-working-for-sudo-on-gnu-linux-works-for-root)

Comment: @avigil its just the way ive always done it. I did without and all worked fine. Thank you

Answer (score 30):

I ran into a similar problem using Python code written by someone else. See http://python-future.org/. future is a module that aids in conversion between Python 2 and 3. It was an easy installation for me by doing `pip3 install future`

Answer (score 15):

I tried install, reinstall, easy_install and conda install but nothing worked for me. I was finally able to import my package by running upgrade on future.

```
pip install -U future
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

None of these work for me, despite uninstalling the module, then reinstalling it with `pip3 install future` I keep getting the error (trying to run ardupilot's `sim_vehicle.py --console --map` in case it matters)

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, solved it using `conda install future`

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, solved it using `easy_install future`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone needs it. This happened when I was trying to builds tests for ArduPilot.

I was facing a similar problem, the pip that you'd have been using was for python3. So you need to install pip for python2.7. You can do that using curl

```
apt-get install curl
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Then you can run

```
pip install future
```

to install future.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
The previous answer isn't effective anymore.
I had to install python 3.7 and use this :

```
apt-get install curl
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.7 get-pip.py
```