# ImportError: No module named future Despite having it installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, catkin, mavlink

The `catkin build` fails due to

```
Errors     << mavlink:make /home/eia-lab1/catkin_ws/logs/mavlink/build.make.005.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eia-lab1/catkin_ws/src/mavlink/pymavlink/tools/mavgen.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pymavlink.generator import mavgen
  File "/home/eia-lab1/catkin_ws/src/mavlink/pymavlink/generator/mavgen.py", line 26, in <module>
    from future import standard_library
ImportError: No module named future
make[2]: *** [paparazzi-v2.0-cxx-stamp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/paparazzi.xml-v2.0.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eia-lab1/catkin_ws/src/mavlink/pymavlink/tools/mavgen.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pymavlink.generator import mavgen
  File "/home/eia-lab1/catkin_ws/src/mavlink/pymavlink/generator/mavgen.py", line 26, in <module>
    from future import standard_library
ImportError: No module named future
make[2]: *** [matrixpilot-v2.0-cxx-stamp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/matrixpilot.xml-v2.0.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Despite having the future installed.**

```
$ pip list | grep fut
future                        0.18.2
```

I've already tried the following:

```
$ pip install -U future 
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: future in /home/eia-lab1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.18.2)

$ sudo -H pip install future
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.15.2)

$ python3 -m pip install future
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: future in /home/eia-lab1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.18.2)

$ pip install future
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: future in /home/eia-lab1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.18.2)

$ pip3 install future
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: future in /home/eia-lab1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.18.2)
```

Resources:

- [No module named future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353905/no-module-named-future)
- https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink/issues/25

I started thinking that this maybe a path sourcing problem!? I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Hmm what about `pip2 install future`

Answer (score 0):

I cant add comments so here I go.

1. you might be using the wrong version of python, try using a newer or older one
2. the module might be in the wrong file

those are the only 2 things I see as you already tried various methods of installing it