# ImportError: No module named pyaudio with sudo

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sudo

I am trying to run a python3 script using sudo on raspberry pi, but it is always giving me an import error the first line, in my case "module pyaudio is not found".

I have tried changing the sudoers file and putting in an env_keep += "my_python_path" like this post : [PYTHONPATH not working for sudo on GNU/Linux (works for root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969540/pythonpath-not-working-for-sudo-on-gnu-linux-works-for-root)
 but it doesn't seem to work.

However, when I run sudo with python2 or when I run python3 without sudo the import errors don't happen. Any suggestions on how to get it work with python3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used `sudo su` to gain root access and everything worked fine.