# Why the ‘sudo nohup python a.py &’ command cannot find numpy？

Tags: python, bash, numpy, ubuntu

I have installed python and numpy,and can run a.py with 'python a.py' command.
a.py is here:

```py
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

But when I run a.py with command '**sudo nohup python a.py &**',no module named numpy.
Detail is shown below in image.
What's more,my linux version is ubuntu 18_04 64.
[Detail img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Wo2.png)

Comment: Did you install numpy in the context of a python virtual environment?  Is `python` resolving to the same command as an ordinary user an in the `sudo` environment?

Comment: Can you run ``sudo python a.py`` successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `sudo` while `import` works properly as root, check this:
[PYTHONPATH not working for sudo on GNU/Linux (works for root)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969540/pythonpath-not-working-for-sudo-on-gnu-linux-works-for-root) may help.