# Python 'keyboard' module working as non-root but not working in sudo (linux)

Tags: python, linux

When I import keyboard module as non-root, it imports fine but when I run python with sudo, it does not work.

[image]

Can someone help me solve this strange error

Comment: Install the library with your own user, not with sudo.

Comment: @nagyl I installed using the user only using `pip3 install keyboard` but I want to run a script with sudo in which I imported keyboard module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969540/pythonpath-not-working-for-sudo-on-gnu-linux-works-for-root

Comment: @PrakharGupta then the other way around. You should download the library as root to be able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the following command and see if it helps.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install keyboard
```